# How to extend window to all edges in macOS?

Tags: macos

How to extend the window size to the edge of the screen on macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences/Dock and use this setting[image: .]

Answer (score 1):

This works from macOS Sierra onwards:

Hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down and double click on the edge of the window when oblique arrow sign appears.